# XCode: framework not found uv. - How to determine the root cause?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an issue with my project in XCode. I checked out my WORKING project in another directory trying to fix another issue. And got the following error during build.

```
    Ld /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CafeManager.app/CafeManager normal (in target 'CafeManager' from project 'CafeManager')
    cd /Users/dj-glock/repos/CafeManagerPRO
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -reproducible -target x86_64-apple-ios12.3-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.4.sdk -L/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.4.sdk/usr/lib/swift -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoringSSL-GRPC -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAnonymousAuthUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAppCheckInterop -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuthInterop -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuthUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreExtension -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreInternal -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabase -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabaseUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseEmailAuthUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFacebookAuthUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestoreUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseGoogleAuthUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseOAuthUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebasePhoneAuthUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorageUI -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMAppAuth -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleSignIn -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImage -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SearchTextField -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftAlgorithms -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/abseil -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++ -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -F/Users/dj-glock/repos/CafeManagerPRO/Pods/FBAEMKit/XCFrameworks -F/Users/dj-glock/repos/CafeManagerPRO/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/XCFrameworks -F/Users/dj-glock/repos/CafeManagerPRO/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics/XCFrameworks -F/Users/dj-glock/repos/CafeManagerPRO/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/XCFrameworks -F/Users/dj-glock/repos/CafeManagerPRO/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/dj-glock/repos/CafeManagerPRO/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBAEMKit -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBSDKCoreKit -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBSDKLoginKit -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport -F/Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport -filelist /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CafeManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CafeManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CafeManager.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CafeManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CafeManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CafeManager_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -debug_variant -fobjc-link-runtime -fprofile-instr-generate -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CafeManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CafeManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CafeManager.swiftmodule -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework Algorithms -framework AppAuth -framework CFNetwork -framework Charts -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework FBAEMKit -framework FBLPromises -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKCoreKit_Basics -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAnonymousAuthUI -framework FirebaseAppCheckInterop -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseAuthInterop -framework FirebaseAuthUI -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreExtension -framework FirebaseCoreInternal -framework FirebaseDatabase -framework FirebaseDatabaseUI -framework FirebaseEmailAuthUI -framework FirebaseFacebookAuthUI -framework FirebaseFirestore -framework FirebaseFirestoreUI -framework FirebaseGoogleAuthUI -framework FirebaseInstallations -framework FirebaseOAuthUI -framework FirebasePhoneAuthUI -framework FirebaseStorage -framework FirebaseStorageUI -framework Foundation -framework GTMAppAuth -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport -framework GoogleSignIn -framework GoogleUtilities -framework ImageIO -framework LocalAuthentication -framework SDWebImage -framework SafariServices -framework SearchTextField -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework absl -framework grpc -framework grpcpp -framework leveldb -framework nanopb -framework openssl_grpc -framework uv -weak_framework AuthenticationServices -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CafeManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CafeManager.build/CafeManager.app-Simulated.xcent -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __ents_der -Xlinker /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CafeManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CafeManager.build/CafeManager.app-Simulated.xcent.der -framework SearchTextField -framework Pods_CafeManager -framework Pods_CafeManager -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CafeManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CafeManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CafeManager_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dj-glock/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CafeManager-aubzkzscyxfselhizehshtfkqmaq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CafeManager.app/CafeManager
ld: framework not found uv
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I searched the Internet for similar errors and tried some things:

- Different types of clean - Cmd Shift K, removed derived data using rm -rf or devCleaner.
- Tried to recreate XCWorkspace by removing it and running pod install
- Tried to detach and update pod:

```
    rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
    rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
    pod deintegrate
    pod update
```

Nothing helped. I cannot even understand who requires this framework "uv" and where to find it. I don't use it explicitly in XCode or in Pods.

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '12.3'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

use_frameworks!
target 'CafeManager' do

pod 'SwiftLint'

pod "SearchTextField"
pod 'Charts', '~> 4.1.0'

pod 'Firebase', '~> 10.2'
pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 12.3'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 12'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 12'
pod 'FirebaseFacebookAuthUI', '~> 12.3'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Any advice how to find and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying almost everything I finished with creating new project. I assume my project was corrupted by some action in the past and nothing helped.

So I created new project and copied my resources and source files from the old one. I also tuned a little bit my Podfile. So now it builds and runs. I have a problem with running tests that use Firebase pod, but it's unrelated question.

My new Podfile, just in case.

```
platform :ios, '12.3'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

target 'MyApp' do
  pod "SearchTextField", '~> 1.2.4'
  pod 'DGCharts', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'Firebase', '~> 10.12.0'
  pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 13.0.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 14.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 14.1.0'
  pod 'FirebaseFacebookAuthUI', '~> 13.0.0'

  target :MyAppTests

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
end
```